# Which data-structure to use

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, datastore

I have millions of files in local drives (ex: c,d,e) of my system. Now to search for a file we can use built-in tools of Windows or commands like "find" in linux. 
If i want to design my own "find" program which should first scan all the directories and store the info either in some file or DB. Now whenever I want to search for a file, we first need to load the info from the DB or file and then search.

I need suggestions to decide which data-structure to use for storing the directory structure which can then be loaded and queried for a given file name.

Since search is based on file name, I thought of using Hashmap, where key will be filename and value will the full-path. Using Trie will make the search slower. Another idea is to use Inverted index. But not sure which once is better.

Thanks.

Comment: You might be better off using msys or cygwin locate.

Answer (score 0):

A hash-table would be really good for this because it has O(1) for find (and insert and remove as well). but the issue is that you can't use a hash-table to do a "ranged search".  A "ranged search" would be like "Find all the files that end with the extension cpp".  If this isn't an issue for you then I would suggest implementing the hash-table.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a memory-based strucure (like a normal hash table). memory structures are good for searching, but you have to load the whole dataset into memory just for searching one record. it's very slow and sometimes the dataset is too big to fit in memory.

I suggest you try some disk-based structure like B-Tree or External Memory Hashmap. they are optimized for disk and you are able to search for a record without loading the whole dataset.

If you don't want to write a disk-based search structure yourself, try Google's LevelDB.